# PDO не работает, если в запросе на запись есть переменная

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ооп, pdo

Если я делаю

```
$db = new Connect();
$link = $_POST['link'];
$db->execute("INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`='test name today', `link`='$link');
```

если подставлять в `link` переменную, то запрос ничего не записывает, а если строчка, так как и в `name` - тогда все работает. Не могу понять в чем причина.

```
Class Connect {
    private $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
    private function connect()
    {
        $config = require_once './components/config.php';

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['dbname'].';charset='.$config['charset'];
        $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password']);

        return $this;
    }
    public function execute($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        return $sth->execute();
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        $sth->execute();

        $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result === false){
            return [];
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: забыли в конце двойные кавычки?

Comment: возможно упустил при копировании, код работает, только если в значениях строка, если использовать переменную, тогда ничего не записивает

Comment: Может переменная __пуста__?

Comment: не пуста, может быть она не доступна в области видимости класа Connect?

Comment: Ну так выведите `$sql` в функции `execute` и смотрите текст запроса.

Comment: Замените ``$db->execute("INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`='test name today', `link`='$link'");`` на ``$sql="INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`='test name today', `link`='$link'"; $db->execute($sql);`` Покажите значение, которое получилось в переменной `$sql`.

Comment: если вывести sql

  "INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`='test name today', `link`='https://google.com'"

как я понимаю, все подставляется, но почему то все равно не работает

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю вам использовать другой подход для обработки переменных для записи, тогда вы не будете теряться с кавычками из-за которых могут возникать проблемы.
Для этого мы перепишем метод `execute()`

```
public function execute($sql, $data)
{
    $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

    return $sth->execute($data);
}
```

А запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
$data = [
    'link' => $link,
    'name' => 'test name today'
    ];

$db->execute("INSERT INTO users (name, link) VALUES (:name, :link)", $data);
```

Comment: если все переменные строчки - работает, как только подставляю переменную - перестает

Comment: @YuriiSenenko попробуйте использовать мой вариант, и напишите работает ли

Comment: я за ваш и говорю, если в $data нету переменных, то работает, если вставляю, то не записывает

Comment: а в уверенны, что в переменных есть данные? сделайте var_dump() переменной, покажите что находится в переменной

Comment: вывел sql запрос полностью и там видно, что данные подставились

Comment: @YuriiSenenko в общем я скопировал ваш код, и попробовал внести данные в мою базу, все работает и с переменной. Возможно у вас неправильны настройки подключения либо поля в бд, либо название таблицы не соответствует

Comment: А вы пробовали именно с переменной?

Comment: @YuriiSenenko да

Comment: Спасибо, скорее всего дело в сервере mysql, но еще попробую пересоздать базу данных.

Comment: только return $sth. возвращать результат execute совершенно бессмысленно